# ComponentSpace.SAML Failed to verify the XML signature

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, single-sign-on, saml

I am using following code/api to verify SAML token using from ComponentSpace.SAML.dll

```
AssertionSignature.Verify(token, cert).
```

The same on environment1 is running fine but on environment2 it's giving "Failed to verify the XML signature" error.

I checked both environment for following points and all are same.

1. OS = Windows 2008 Server
2. .Net Framework = 4
3. All Windows Updates =  Up to date
4. Certificate which is used to verified SAML Token -  Valid, Exist and not expired.

Please suggest how to tackle this error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with support for SHA-256 XML signatures.
SHA-256 support is included in Windows 2008 R2 but I'm not sure if it is with Windows 2008.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2014/2949927

My recommendation is to move to Windows 2008 R2 or later and ensure all service packs are installed.

Comment: My Both environment is  Windows 2008 R2 only. Sorry I missed in original question

Comment: Try installing ASP.NET 4.6.2 or higher on the failing system.